# Aligning comments in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, comments

Type these two lines in VB.NET (VS2010):

```
Dim a = 10                             'Comment 1
If a > 10 Then DoSomething()           'Comment 2
```

As soon as you press `ENTER` on the second line, the editor for some strange reason, removes all the spaces between the code and the comment, leaving it less readable. Doesn't matter whether you use `TAB`s or spaces.

I know I can type these on top of the code lines, but my question is; why is this so? Are there any other cases in which it will behave like that?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using visual studio? If yes, then

Try going to Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> Basic -> VB Specific

There uncheck the **"Pretty listing (reformatting) of code"** checkbox.

That should fix it.

Comment: That would kill the very feature itself. On-the-fly reformatting is a big help for experienced VB.NET programmers. I'm just concerned about the irregular behavior in the two cases i mentioned.

Comment: I agree, but it looks like the comment formatting is also controlled by this.